# Teradata fastload performance issue

Tags: teradata, informatica

Hi I have a Teradata fast load which is inserting 10lac of data in target in 30 mins.
when I checked the logs I can see it is taking 1lack records in 1 iteration and 3 mins to complete each iteration and running in 10 iterations to complete this activity.
Is there any way in which we can increase the fast load insert batch size to more than 1lac records per iteration.

I have looked for different options to inc the batch size but not getting any results any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I see you have tagged [informatica]. Are you invoking the Teradata load process (TPT API Load or external FastLoad) from Informatica, running the FastLoad command-line utility directly, or using the FastLoad "protocol" from some other driver / tool? This is really a tool question and not a Teradata question per se.

Comment: I see 'lac' and 'lack'. I assume you mean lakh. Can you rather stick to more common thousands or millions? Like 1M instead of 10lac? Now, can you share the logs? It would make things easier. Lastly, please mention which Informatica version do you work with. And check Commit Interval propety - this is likely the one you need to set according to your needs.